# How do I disable Firefox logging in Selenium using Geckodriver?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, logging, geckodriver

I am using:

- firefox version 50.1.0
- geckodriver version 0.11.1
- selenium-java 3.0.1

I have tried

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.browser.ignore", true);
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.driver.ignore", true);
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.profiler.ignore", true);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and

```
LoggingPreferences preferences = new LoggingPreferences();
preferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.OFF);
preferences.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.OFF);
preferences.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.OFF);
preferences.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.OFF);
preferences.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.OFF);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, preferences);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

neither of these methods does anything to stop logging.
Here is console output if that helps somehow:

- first method: http://pastebin.com/23nate2G
- second method: http://pastebin.com/NwmWEeXT

For those wondering, i have log4j 1.2.17 in my `pom.xml` but have no `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` and I do not use it at all.

---

To clarify: when I say logging I mean the console output in IntelliJ IDEA. I am using Java.

Comment: Why are u using geckodriver ? It's needed for Firefox ? oh ok got it, it's new in selenium 3

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Geckodriver is needed for Firefox with selenium 3.0.0 and up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off the Marionette/gecko driver logs in selenium 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696695/how-to-turn-off-the-marionette-gecko-driver-logs-in-selenium-3)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To not see the logs in the console you can use the following:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","src/main/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe");
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"/dev/null");

return new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: How would I set the marionette log level to "warn"?

Comment: From https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.html#BROWSER_LOGFILE, `BROWSER_LOGFILE` defines the location of the file where Firefox log should be stored --> but I don't see the logfile under /dev/null (this file does not exist) Does /dev/null save it to nowhere?

Comment: @IceTea checkout this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device `/dev/null` discards everything, its like a trash

Answer (score 6):

You can define the desired logging level over command line in geckodriver.exe.

```
geckodriver.exe -help    
USAGE:
    geckodriver.exe [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]   
...
OPTIONS:
        --log <LEVEL>
            Set Gecko log level [values: fatal, error, warn, info, config,
            debug, trace]
```

If you use geckodriver from selenium, you have two option:

- Start geckodriver.exe separately with custom arguments, and use it from selenium over RemoteWebDriver
- Create a custom wrapper, to add extra parameters to geckodriver.exe

Example geckodriver wrapper bat file (for windows):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting geckodriver: %0 %*
.\GeckoDriver\geckodriver.exe --log fatal %* > NUL 2>&1
```

In java you can define the geckodriver executable path, over **webdriver.gecko.driver** system property:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:/selenium/geckodriver/gdrvwrapper.bat");
```

Comment: I went with this answer but the setting the log level didn't do anything for me on linux. It worked because the output is redirected to null. You can try this by not adding the > NUL 2>& portion. I added the linux version below

Comment: Is the bat file still needed? or is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: System properties allow you to do it pragmatically. see the other answer(s)

Comment: How would I add geckodriver log level from java?

Answer (score 5):

Just do this

```
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE,"true");
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"/dev/null");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: How would one set the log level to `warn`?

Answer (score 3):

I am using headless Firefox driver in C#.
To disable geckoDriver logging console, below code it seems to be working for me:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("--headless");
options.LogLevel = FirefoxDriverLogLevel.Fatal;
WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

For selenium 3.14.0 , this is working

```
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE,"/dev/null");
```

Comment: System is coming from jdk, make sure your evironment has jdk installed and in the path

Answer (score 0):

```
  GeckoDriverService gecko = new GeckoDriverService(new File("c:/selenium/geckodriver.exe"), 4444, ImmutableList.of("--log=fatal"), ImmutableMap.of());
  gecko.sendOutputTo(new FileOutputStream("gecko_log.txt"));
  gecko.start();

  FirefoxOptions opts = new FirefoxOptions().setLogLevel(Level.OFF);
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = opts.addTo(DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
  capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(gecko, capabilities);
```

Comment: I get an error AND a deprecation warning even if I change it not to give errors anymore. This must be an old version of Selenium

Answer (score 0):

This is the linux version for @voji answer above. Note as I said above in the comment. I don't believe the --log fatal does anything, at least not on linux. 
However the redirect to NULL works well enough for me

```
"webdriver.gecko.driver": "/path-to-driver/geckodriver.sh
```

filename: geckodriver.sh (executable)

```
#! /bin/bash
echo " ARGS: " $@
geckodriver --log fatal "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hacky but it can quickly get the job done without any coding required. Given that you know the exact location of your file and you run your code on Linux you can just cd into that dir and

```
rm geckodriver.log
ln -s /dev/null geckodriver.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.init", true);
```

works, because it fools the webdriver into believing the log has already been initialized, so it won't initialize it and no log will be produced.