# how to turn off the gecko driver (0.18v) logs in selenium 3.5.3

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

[.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZyO9.png)

Here are these logs that are continuously coming till the end line of code and its very irritating. i need help to turn off these logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set verbosity of marionette driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002918/how-to-set-verbosity-of-marionette-driver)

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue of selenium 3.01 and above. I have read it from this [link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/456#issuecomment-277256588):

You can use `LoggingPreferences` class and enable the properties. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696695/how-to-turn-off-the-marinate-gecko-driver-logs-in-selenium-3) it may helps you:

Comment: I guess, there has been some issue with selenium jar 3.0 and above thats why it is not achievable

Comment: Thanks for the effort but i guess it is an issue in selenium 3.0 and above versions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a windows batch file with below commands and provide that batch file as a parameter while setting the gecko driver property. Please see the below code.

Batch File as **gecko.bat**:

```
@ECHO OFF
C:\Selenium\****\geckodriver.exe --log fatal %* > NUL 2>&1
```

Set Gecko driver system property in the script before initializing the Firefox driver. Please see below

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/Selenium/***/gecko.bat");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In the above code `C:\Selenium\****\geckodriver.exe` is the path of the geckodriver.exe in your PC and `C:/Selenium/***/gecko.bat` is the path of the batch you created and saved on your PC.

This will work for sure. All the best.

Comment: According to your solution it is not even connecting to firefox driver.